# pyspark with pandas udf giving java.io.EOFException while writing to CSV

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow, pandas-udf

pyspark code using pandas udf functions , works fine with df.limit(20).collect() & write to csv for 20 records. But when i try write 100 records to csv it fails with java.io.EOFException error. Same code works fine with regular udf functions (not pandas udf). Not clear on how to troubleshoot , looking for guidance

***pandas udf to find names using flairnlp model***

```
#Define Flair Function - pandas udf
@pandas_udf("array<string>")
def pu_find_names_flair(iterator: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    
   
for textSr in iterator:
    sentences = []
    for text in textSr:
        sentences.append(Sentence(text))
        
    tagger.predict(sentences)
    Flairresult = []
    
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        Flairresultentity = []
        # iterate over entities and print each
        for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
            if entity.get_label("ner").value in ["PER", "LOC", "ORG"]:
                Flairresultentity.append((entity.text))
        Flairresult.append(Flairresultentity)        
    yield pd.Series(Flairresult)
```

***Another pandas udf to find & replace strings passed in text***

```
  #Mask pii in Call transcripts - pandas udf
  @pandas_udf("string")
  def pu_mask_all_pii(iterator: Iterator[Tuple[pd.Series, pd.Series]]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
"""
Pandas UDF to remove PII from text.
:param: Iterators for two df columns
:return: return iterator
"""

   
for text, pii_list in iterator:

    result = []
    for text, tokens in zip(text, pii_list):
        tokens = sorted(tokens,key=len, reverse=True)
        pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, tokens))
        text = re.sub(pat, lambda g: 'X' * len(g.group()), str(text), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        result.append(text)
        
    yield pd.Series(result)
```

***pyspark dataframe code***

```
exclude_pii_words = ['@@@@@@@@','#####']
dfs= dfs.limit(100)
dfs=dfs.withColumn("pii_flairner",pu_find_names_flair(col("CALL_TRANSCRIPT")))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('pii_allmethods', array_except(array_distinct(concat(dfs["pii_bertner"], 
dfs["pii_regex_spacy"], dfs["pii_flairner"])),array(*map(lit,exclude_pii_words))))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('FULL_TRANSCRIPT', pu_mask_all_pii(col("CALL_TRANSCRIPT"), 
                                          col("pii_allmethods")))

dfs = dfs.withColumn('pii_flairner', concat_ws(",",col("pii_flairner")))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('pii_regex_spacy', concat_ws(",",col("pii_regex_spacy")))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('pii_bertner', concat_ws(",",col("pii_bertner")))
dfs = dfs.withColumn('pii_allmethods', concat_ws(",",col("pii_allmethods")))

dfs.limit(20).select('FULL_TRANSCRIPT').collect()  # Works fine

dfs.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv("<filename>") #Errors
```

***Exception***

```
23/03/27 00:44:19 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 14) (10.192.99.70 executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:678)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:667)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:595)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:521)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2241)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:313)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:88)
... 23 more
```

***pyarrow versions***

```
pyarrow==11.0.0
numpy==1.23.3
pandas==1.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating PyArrow MaxRecordsper batch based on cluster config. By default it is 10k. For me it works only upto 100 and anything beyond that pyspark code fails with EOF exception or socket connection errors from PyArrow.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch","100")
```